# generate pdf with dynamic content using scala and play framework

Tags: angularjs, scala, pdf, playframework

I have a list of sessions when clicking on a session I get it and send the id to my method using angularJs:

```
  def getSession(idSession: UUID) = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    sessionService.findById(idSession).map {
      case Some(session) =>
        Ok(views.html.result.printPdf(session))
      case None => NotFound(Json.toJson("Not found"))

    }
  }
```

My method works fine but it don't redirect to the view "prindpdf" also how can I call my second function which generate the pdf and take the session as parameter here is my second function:

```
  def homepage: Action[AnyContent] = Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(new PdfGenerator().toBytes(views.html.result.printPdf("Your PDF is generated"), "http://localhost:9000")).as("application/pdf")
  }
```

and this is my view:

```
@(message: models.Session)
@mainPdf("Welcome") {
    Image: <img src="/public/images/favicon.png"/><br/>
    Hello world! <br/>
    @message
}
```